# Apache не хватает места на диске, хотя место есть

Tags: php, linux, apache, веб-сервер, файловая-система

Странная ситуация использую PHP метод [disk_free_space](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.disk-free-space.php) для определения свободного места на диске. Результат 1.36 гигабайта. Хотя проверяя место на диске командой **df -h** (для чистоты эксперимента под тем же пользователем, под которым работает Apache) вижу, что доступно 11 гигабайт. Как такое может быть? И как увеличить доступное апачу место?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как вызываете `disk_free_space` и вывод ее, возможно вы неверно перевели в гигабайты.

Comment: А он вам случайно место не в каталоге /tmp показал ?

Comment: Проблема решена. Дело в том, что тот каталог у которого cms пыталась узнать место - не совсем каталог, это примонтированный через curlftpfs ftp сервер. Ну собственно по этому cms не могла получить объём свободного места. Всем спасибо.